# Matrices problem?

Tags: matrices

Does anyone know how to do this?

1.) Write two matrices A and B such that AB = BA, but neither A nor B is the identity matrix.

Comment: I take it you are interested in two *distinct* matrices $A$, $B$, else put $A = B$. Or let $A$ or $B$ be the zero matrix. But more importantly, are you assigning *us* homework?

Answer (score 1):

Take any polynomial $P$ and let $B=P(A)$ then clearly
$$AP(A)=P(A)A$$
since $A$ commutes with $I$ and with itself.